# Error Messages when Inadyn reapplies IP to dynamic DNS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ip, dynamic-dns

While i keep having access from outside my home network when hitting my *"freedns"* dynamic DNS, when typing **"more /var/log/messages |grep INADYN"** it gives me the errors below.

I wonder what's wrong as i am not losing connection to my home IP address at any point despite the increased number disconnections i am getting because of my bad home line.

Maybe i should put something on **"freedns"** site?

Below are the logs i am getting right after i am disconnecting and rasp inadyn daemon applies the new ip to the dynamic DNS:

> Feb  4 23:26:52 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: INADYN: Started 'INADYN
>   version 1.96.2' - dynamic DNS updater.
>
> Feb  4 23:26:53 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: I:INADYN: IP address for
>   alias 'mydnsname.freednsdomain.com' needs update to 'x.x.x.x'
>
> Feb  4 23:26:55 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: I:INADYN: Alias
>   'mydnsname.freednsdomain.com' to IP 'x.x.x.x' updated successful.
>
> Feb  4 23:36:52 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: W: DYNDNS: Error
>   'RC_IP_CONNECT_FAILED' (0x13) when talking to IP server
>
> Feb  4 23:36:52 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: W:'RC_IP_CONNECT_FAILED'
>   (0x13) updating the IPs. (it 13)
>
> Feb  4 23:41:31 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: W: DYNDNS: Error
>   'RC_IP_CONNECT_FAILED' (0x13) when talking to IP server
>
> Feb  4 23:41:31 myraspberrypi INADYN[1998]: W:'RC_IP_CONNECT_FAILED'
>   (0x13) updating the IPs. (it 17)

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I don't have 50 reputation points to put a comment)

I have been having this same problem for over many years (on Ubuntu and now on Arch Linux). I see 2 bad solutions that can help you for making inadyn for a few days. *Note that these will not fix your problem for good.*

1. Restart your service (for example with systemd just type systemctl restart inadyn). Then check the status of the service (systemctl status inadyn).
2. Restart your computer (in your case your RaspberryPi). This will force the restart of the service.

You could also launch a cron job that will restart your inadyn service every day/week ... for me it keeps crashing every 2 or 3 weeks.

Hope someone will offer a real solution as my solutions are just like putting ducktape to hold a door on a car ;-)